# Why am I getting every other line?

Tags: python, count, cpu-word

I am trying to create a Python code for counting the number of words per line of a text.

**My text** consists of the following movie titles:

```
We Still Steal the Old Way
Demon
Immortal Wars
The Portal
Selfie from Hell
The Bad Nun
Astro
Diggerz: Black Lung Rises
Battle Drone
How to Train Your Dragon 3
```

**The code I created is as follows:**

```
f = open('C:/movies/sample06.txt') 
for x in f: 
    line = f.readline()
    print(line, end='')
    words = line.split(" ")
    print(words)
    num_words = len(words)
    print(num_words)
```

And what I get is:

```
Demon
['Demon\n']
1

The Portal
['The', 'Portal\n']
2

The Bad Nun
['The', 'Bad', 'Nun\n']
3

Diggerz: Black Lung Rises
['Diggerz:', 'Black', 'Lung', 'Rises\n']
4

How to Train Your Dragon 3
['How', 'to', 'Train', 'Your', 'Dragon', '3\n']
6
```

**My question is:** 
How can I get the results for each and every movie title above? 
The result here showed the results of every other movie title.

Comment: Use loops. Read some documentation and see similar questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: There is no way the code that you gave us here can read more than the first line of the file. So, please paste the exact code that you ran and the exact output that you obtained.

Comment: You're right. I edited the code by adding: for x in f:

Answer (score 1):

Your code starts with:

```
f = open('C:/movies/sample06.txt') 
for x in f: 
    line = f.readline()
```

You iterate on your file `f` line by line in the `for` loop. But as soon as the next line in the file got read into `x`, you read the following one into `line`. As you don't do anything with `x`, this line gets lost.

So, you don't have to use `readline()` to iterate on the lines of your file. Just do:

```
with open('C:/movies/sample06.txt') as f: 
    for line in f: 
        print(line, end='')
        words = line.split(" ")
        print(words)
        num_words = len(words)
        print(num_words)
```

Note the `with open....` idiom that guarantees that your file gets closed whatever happens in your script.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer which helps me avoid sitting up all night.

Comment: You're welcome! :) If you feel that an answer has solved your problem, you may accept it by checking the mark on the left and/or upvote it once you have enough reputation. And enjoy your night!